# How to I get Excel to take a user id in one table, match it in another, return only the most recent value, and ignore older values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need Excel to take the userID from Table A, match it to Table B and return the most recent SaleDate only,
and ignore older SaleDate entries. In addition, I need to also return the corresponding "Item" in Table B.
I usually go with Index and Match but it stops at the first instance in Table B only. I've searched a lot of
different solutions but nothing fits my exact situation. If possible I'd like to just use formulas to do this.

```
(old) Table A

|userID| company  | LastSaleDate    | Item
______________________________________________
|1     | catworld |                 | 
|2     | fishworld|                 | 
|3     | dogworld |                 | 


Table B

|userID| company  | SaleDate    | Item |
________________________________________
|1     | catworld | 01/01/2005  | toy   |
|1     | catworld | 01/03/2017  | leash |
|2     | fishworld| 05/05/2019  | tank  |
|3     | dogworld | 02/01/2005  | food  |
|3     | dogworld | 02/03/2017  | toy   |


(new) Table A

|userID| company  | LastSaleDate    | Item
______________________________________________
|1     | catworld | 01/03/2017      | leash
|2     | fishworld| 05/05/2019      | tank
|3     | dogworld | 02/03/2017      | toy
```

Any help or ideas would be grealy appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: copy table B to Table A.  Order by lastSaleDate descending.  Then use Remove duplicates based on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You may also sort Table B by UserID, smallest to largetest. Then sort by Saledate, oldest to newest.

[image]

Then enter the formula below into the first cell of **LastSaleDate**, then fill down.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,F$2:I$8,3)`

Enter `=VLOOKUP(A2,F$2:I$8,4)` into the first cell of **Item**, then fill down.